# How can I draw something in screen pixel coordinates in a OnDrawGizmos in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to draw a rect in screen pixel coordinates in `OnDrawGizmos` in a MonoBehaviour

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
   void OnDrawGizmos()
   {
       Rect rect = new Rect(10, 10, 150, 100);
       UnityEditor.Handles.DrawSolidRectangleWithOutline(rect, Color.black, Color.white);
   }
}
```

Those values in `rect` end up being world space coords oriented toward the screen relative to the `Transform` of the `GameObject` this script is attached to.

I'd like to just draw in pixels on the screen where 0, 0 is the top left of the screen. Do I need to get out the camera and compute those positions relative to the current GameObject's transform or is there an easier way?

Comment: can you attach this script to your camera? If not then does [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) help?

Comment: No I can't attach the script to my camera. Besides, `OnDrawGizmos` is called for every scene view so attaching it to the camera doesn't make a lot of sense. As for `WorldToScreenPoint` that doesn't really help as the `rect` above is in world units. In a sense I need `ScreenToWorldPoint` which exits but doesn't really give me the correct values since rect is not in world units

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, and I found that you just need to add `Handles.BeginGUI();` to change to screen coordinate instead of world coordinate and you can do something like :

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
   void OnDrawGizmos()
   {
       Rect rect = new Rect(10, 10, 150, 100);
       UnityEditor.Handles.BeginGUI();
       UnityEditor.Handles.DrawSolidRectangleWithOutline(rect, Color.black, Color.white);
       UnityEditor.Handles.EndGUI();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is **NOT** the solution I was looking for. The solution I wanted was some way to just tell Unity I want to draw in 2D and start using the `GUI`, `GUILayout` functions but when I tried to use them I got errors. Maybe someone has an example?

In lieu of that here's some code to compute the correct world coordinates for the desired screen coordinates

```
Vector3 ScreenToWorld(float x, float y) {
    Camera camera = Camera.current;
    Vector3 s = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    return camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x, camera.pixelHeight - y, s.z));
}

Rect ScreenRect(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    Vector3 tl = ScreenToWorld(x, y);
    Vector3 br = ScreenToWorld(x + w, y + h);
    return new Rect(tl.x, tl.y, br.x - tl.x, br.y - tl.y);
}
```

So with that this seems to work

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
   void OnDrawGizmos()
   {
       Rect rect = ScreenRect(10, 10, 150, 100);
       UnityEditor.Handles.DrawSolidRectangleWithOutline(rect, Color.black, Color.white);
   }

...
```